# Another proof for impossibility of covering $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with a set of varieties of cardinality less than $2^{\aleph_0}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, algebraic-geometry, alternative-proof

Let $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be the affine $n$-space. Let $\{V_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha \in \Gamma}$ be a set of real varieteis such that $\mathbb{R}^{n} \subseteq {\bigcup V_{\alpha}}.$ Prove that $|\Gamma| \geq 2^{\aleph_{0}}$

---

I know that one can take the set $A =\{(t^{a_{1}},...,t^{a_{n}}) | t \in [0,1],\hspace{0.2cm} a_{1},...,a_{n} \text{ such that they are linearly independent over} \hspace{0.2cm}\mathbb{Q}\}$ and show that every polynomial intersects with this set in finitly many points and prove the statement.

But now does anyone know rather a different proof of this statement?

Comment: The Baire Category Theorem may give a solution: show that every proper variety is nowhere dense. Although this may bring up CH shenanigans, since BCT only guarantees not-countable, not necessarily $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Thank you. Based on what you said, I think we can show that if a polynomial is equal to zero over an open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ then it is itself the zero polynomial and this will prove the statement by assuming CH, and the case of not assuming the CH remains.